# IabHelper: Purchase canceled - Response: 5:Developer Error

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Past few days I developing in-app purchase. I was testing this very well. When I changed SKU adding postfix then buy process ended wiht response "5:Developer Error" I had read all coresponding answers and trying put variety solutions:

- my SKU items are active
- app in alpha channel is published
- I have  difrent account for developer console and tester
- app in Google Play   and in device is sign with the same key
- tested with second device and    another tester
- when delete previous added postfix nothing changed

Very interesting is fact that problem appear after little change in SKU. Earlier everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

When run first time purches flow the oldSku must be null or empty list.